# offset svg path element relative to its own size

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, transform

I'm trying to offset svg `path` element using `tranform:'tranlate(100%,0)'` (while `transformBox:'fill-box`) but it seems that `path` elements does not offset the same way `circle` or `rect` does.

when offseting circle elements:

```js
  <circle r="10" />
  <g style={{ transform: "translate(100%)", transformBox: "fill-box" }}>
    <circle r="10" fill="purple" />
  </g>
```

we will get the desired outcome: [image]

when doing the same with path(scaled so could be seen):

```js
const PathSvg = ({ stroke = "black" }) => (
  <g transform="scale(10)">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 1 0.5 L 0 1 L 0.25 0.5 z" stroke={stroke} />
  </g>
);

<h2>svg path</h2>
<svg overflow={"visible"}>
  <PathSvg />
  <g style={{ transform: "translate(100%)", transformBox: "fill-box" }}>
    <PathSvg stroke="purple" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

we will get this [image]

I've also tried using different `transformBox` but none give the desired outcome.

why on the SVG path element does transform behave differently?

#### Demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-path-vs-other-svgs-tranform-jdiym?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The stroke-box on most browsers is an overestimate, particularly on paths that can have pointy bits. If you stick to fills you'll find things work much better.

Comment: but it's not even close to being the exact result, you are saying that this is a problem with the implementation of transform when tranformbox:'fill-box'?

Comment: no, I'm saying stroke-box is a problem. You're not using fill-box with the path in your demo.

Answer (score 1):

This is getting close to working. The `transform-box: stroke-box` is definitely not working on `<path>`. Here I changed the stroke to fill.

```html
<h2>svg path</h2>
<svg style="overflow: visible">
  <defs>
    <g id="path1" transform="scale(100)">
      <path d="M 0 0 L 1 0.5 L 0 1 L 0.25 0.5 z" />
    </g>
  </defs>
  <use href="#path1" fill="orange"/>
  <g style="transform: translate(100%, 0); transform-box: fill-box;">
    <use href="#path1" fill="purple"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: this is good but the problem here that I let the user provide jsx that could be svg element with stroke. I can't rely that the SVG shape stroke would be fill.
but can you explain how did you duplicate that shape from stroke stroke to fill stroke